# CSS. Убрать background-color под border

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте!
background-origin контролирует поведение картинки под border, но не контролирует поведение цвета..

Я хочу чтоб background-color вписывался только в content-box. Подскажите как?

```css
.elem {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: orange;
  border:10px dotted red;
  background-origin:content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem"></div>
```

Comment: background-clip: padding-box;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
.elem {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: orange;
  border: 10px dotted red;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem"></div>
```

Comment: а зачем `background-origin: content-box`, если тут нет картинки?

Comment: я просто дописал то что нужно в код автора...